# Inconsistent GPIO values on Beaglebone Black running Debian

Tags: gpio, beaglebone-black, debian

I'm trying to use GPIO on my Beaglebone Black, but I'm running into some behavior I don't understand. I have two pins (gpios 27 and 61) configured to input with `active_low` set to `0`. There is nothing connected to either pin (or any pin on the board for that matter), but one of the pins (gpio 61) is showing a value of `1` while gpio 27 shows a value of 0.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Here are the exact steps I took to get this result:

```
echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 61 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio61/direction
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value
0
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/active_low
0
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio61/value
1
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio61/active_low
0
```

Comment: Without anything connected to a general purpose input the value is undefined or in other words floating and can take on the value of high or low. To combat this, normally pull-up or pull-down resistors are used either externally or internally.

Comment: DigitalNinja is correct. You should not rely on a CMOS input to have one value or the other when nothing is connected to it.

Comment: Read [Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scba004).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that one or both GPIOs are not floating. Those states that you see could be caused by the internal pullup/pulldown resisters.

Are you familiar with Debian's device tree overlays? That is what you would use to configure the I/O pins on the BBB. Besides input and output, you can configure pins for drive-strength and enable/disable pullup and pulldown resistors.

Have a look here for details:
http://derekmolloy.ie/gpios-on-the-beaglebone-black-using-device-tree-overlays/

Comment: You can also enable/disable internal pullup/pulldown using config-pin options like 'gpio_pu', 'gpio_pd' and 'gpio'

Comment: @AvadhanaSolutions - Yes, now you can. But that wasn't available four years ago.